# Formulario de busqueda en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy realizando una sección de noticias, el cual para buscar una noticia tengo el siguiente formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La duda que tengo es, como puedo hacer un buscador, dependiendo del numero de campos que se complete. Por ejemplo, alguien puede buscar una noticia solo por palabra clave, o fecha. U otras persona pueden completar Sector, empresa, fuente, o todos los campos, es decir que se puede hacer una búsqueda con cualquier campo y cualquier combinación de estos

Comment: Todos esos campos de búsqueda son propiedades del model noticias?

Comment: Si @LeonardoCabré

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacerlo de esta manera, en base a los campos que recibis en el request vas armando la consulta, por ejemplo:

Se inicia la nueva query para el modelo Noticia

```
$noticia = Noticia::newQuery();
```

Un ejemplo de busqueda en base a un campo propio de noticia:

```
if($request->has('palabra_clave')){
    $noticia->where('nombre', 'like', $request->palabra_clave);
}
```

Algún ejemplo de búsqueda en base a relaciónes del modelo `Noticia` con otros modelos, en este caso suponiendo que existe un modelo `Sector` y un modelo `Fuente` y que sus relaciones están declaradas como `sector` y `fuente` respectivamente:

```
if($request->has('sector')){
    $noticia->whereHas('sector', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre', 'like', $request->sector);
    });
}

if($request->has('fuente')){
    $noticia->whereHas('fuente', function ($query) {
        $query->where('nombre', 'like', $request->fuente);
    });
}
```

Por ultimo ejecutamos la query que se fue armando y le devolvemos el resultado a la vista:

```
$noticias = $noticias->get();
return view('tuvista', compact('noticias'));
```

Aqui el código tal como podría verse en un método de búsqueda:

```
public function busqueda(Request $request){
    $noticia = Noticia::newQuery();

    if($request->has('palabra_clave')){
        $noticia->where('nombre', 'like', $request->palabra_clave);
    }

    if($request->has('sector')){
        $noticia->whereHas('sector', function ($query) {
            $query->where('nombre', 'like', $request->sector);
        });
    }

    if($request->has('fuente')){
        $noticia->whereHas('fuente', function ($query) {
            $query->where('nombre', 'like', $request->fuente);
        });
    }

    $noticias = $noticias->get();
    return view('tuvista', compact('noticias'));
}
```